# ASP.NET MVC модель обнуляется

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте!

Есть HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ViewModel _model;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {       
        return View((_model = new ViewModel()));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Click(int n)
    {
        _model.Count.Number += n;
        return PartialView("Count", _model.Count);
    }
}
```

Click - метод, вызываемый при помощи Ajax по нажатию кнопки. Вопрос - почему при заходе в метод Click модель _model равна null? Она же создается в Index?

Answer (score 1):

На каждый запрос от клиента по адресу `.../Home/<action name>` ASP.NET MVC создает новый объект типа `HomeController` с полем `_model` равным `null`.

```
// ViewModel _model; - убрать

private ViewModel GetModel()
{
  ViewModel _model = (ViewModel)Session["homeViewModel"];
  if (_model == null)
  {
    ViewModel _model = new ViewModel();
    Session["homeViewModel"] = _model;
  }
  return _model;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{       
  ViewModel _model = GetModel();
  return View(_model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Click(int n)
{
  ViewModel _model = GetModel();
  _model.Count.Number += n;
  return PartialView("Count", _model.Count);
}
```

Comment: И, получается, хранить и читать данные из модели на получится? Даже при условии, что я не обновляю страницу, а только меняю содержание какого-то div-a?

Comment: храните модель в сессии